# Vlookup in SQl table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, subquery

table1

```
Agent           id
A              1
B              2
C              3 
D              4
E              5
```

table2

```
Agent          id
C               3 
D               4
```

output:

```
Agent           id
A               1
B               2 
E               3
```

Comment: SQL tables have no operation called "vlookup".  Your question is not clear.

Comment: The equivalent of a `VLookup` in SQL would probably *literally* be a subquery with a lateral join in the `WHERE`, though you are likely after a proper `JOIN` in the `FROM`.

Comment: In source data `Agent='E'` has `id=5`, in the output it has `id=3`. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want `not exists`?

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.agent = t1.agent and t2.id = t1.id)
```

This brings records of `table1` for which there is no corresponding record in `table2`. I assumed that you want to match on both columns: you might to review that, and adapt the `where` clause of the subquery accordingly.